# Android: Invoke Gallery via intent and select an Image

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-gallery

using several codes available throughout the site, I built a small application that would invoke Gallery intent and when a image is selected the path is retured.

```
public class SDCardImagesActivity extends Activity {
    final int REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE= 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.header);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(requestCode) { 
        case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();


                Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

                Toast.makeText(SDCardImagesActivity.this, "selected", 2000).show();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But when I run this program I get following exception

```
08-09 15:12:53.191: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26694): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

Can someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is returning 0 rows, that's why you are getting an error CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException = trying to access first row of a cursor with 0 rows.

Have you made sure their are pics on the said media (SD card) ?

Comment: yep there are images. when I select an image only this exception thrown. Arrayoutofbound :(

Comment: it was a permission issue. I was trying to access the images that I created using my application, and it seems there are no privillage for that. When I try images taken by native camera, it is working like a charm.